# apt-offline apt-get upgrade still trying to connect to online server for upgrade even though packages have been synced already

Tags: debian, apt, upgrade, apt-offline

I have a server which can't go online because of some policy. So I have to update it using apt-offline.
So far it has worked for me nicely on other servers, but this one doesn't really.

- I created the sig file, moved it to an online server
- I created the bundle on the online server using the sig file
- I moved the bundle back to the offline server
- I installed the bundle, the output shows synced for all repros
- I call `apt-get upgrade`, it shows me all the packages that were just synced
- The server tries to connect to an internet server `0% [Connecting to cdn.debian.net] [Connecting to security.debian.org]`, see below, even though the output shows that it has just synced packages from the bundle... I don't get it, what am I doing wrong?

See here the `apt-offline install` command and the `apt-get upgrade` command

```
root@CFRLJY1:~# apt-offline install /media/usb/bundle-24-11-2015-3.zip
gpgv: Signature made Tue Nov 24 04:54:22 2015 HKT using RSA key ID 46925553
gpgv: Good signature from "Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (7.0/wheezy) <ftpmaster@debian.org>"
gpgv: Signature made Tue Nov 24 04:54:22 2015 HKT using RSA key ID 2B90D010
gpgv: Good signature from "Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (8/jessie) <ftpmaster@debian.org>"
gpgv: Signature made Sat Sep  5 19:47:40 2015 HKT using RSA key ID 46925553
gpgv: Good signature from "Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (7.0/wheezy) <ftpmaster@debian.org>"
gpgv: Signature made Sat Sep  5 19:47:40 2015 HKT using RSA key ID 2B90D010
gpgv: Good signature from "Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (8/jessie) <ftpmaster@debian.org>"
gpgv: Signature made Sat Sep  5 19:47:55 2015 HKT using RSA key ID 65FFB764
gpgv: Good signature from "Wheezy Stable Release Key <debian-release@lists.debian.org>"
gpgv: Signature made Mon Nov 23 08:50:55 2015 HKT using RSA key ID C857C906
gpgv: Good signature from "Debian Security Archive Automatic Signing Key (8/jessie) <ftpmaster@debian.org>"
gpgv: Signature made Mon Nov 23 08:50:55 2015 HKT using RSA key ID 46925553
gpgv: Good signature from "Debian Archive Automatic Signing Key (7.0/wheezy) <ftpmaster@debian.org>"
/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ftp.cn.debian.org_debian_dists_wheezy-updates_Release synced.
/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ftp.cn.debian.org_debian_dists_wheezy-updates_Release.gpg synced.
/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ftp.cn.debian.org_debian_dists_wheezy-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages synced.
/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ftp.cn.debian.org_debian_dists_wheezy-updates_main_i18n_Translation-en synced.
/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ftp.cn.debian.org_debian_dists_wheezy-updates_main_source_Sources synced.
/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ftp.cn.debian.org_debian_dists_wheezy-updates_Release synced.
/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ftp.cn.debian.org_debian_dists_wheezy-updates_Release.gpg synced.
/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ftp.cn.debian.org_debian_dists_wheezy-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages synced.
/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ftp.cn.debian.org_debian_dists_wheezy-updates_main_i18n_Translation-en synced.
/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ftp.cn.debian.org_debian_dists_wheezy-updates_main_source_Sources synced.
/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ftp.cn.debian.org_debian_dists_wheezy_Release synced.
/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ftp.cn.debian.org_debian_dists_wheezy_Release.gpg synced.
/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ftp.cn.debian.org_debian_dists_wheezy_contrib_binary-amd64_Packages synced.
/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ftp.cn.debian.org_debian_dists_wheezy_contrib_i18n_Translation-en synced.
/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ftp.cn.debian.org_debian_dists_wheezy_main_binary-amd64_Packages synced.
/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ftp.cn.debian.org_debian_dists_wheezy_main_i18n_Translation-en synced.
/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ftp.cn.debian.org_debian_dists_wheezy_main_source_Sources synced.
/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ftp.cn.debian.org_debian_dists_wheezy_non-free_binary-amd64_Packages synced.
/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ftp.cn.debian.org_debian_dists_wheezy_non-free_i18n_Translation-en synced.
/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.debian.org_dists_wheezy_updates_Release synced.
/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.debian.org_dists_wheezy_updates_Release.gpg synced.
/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.debian.org_dists_wheezy_updates_contrib_binary-amd64_Packages synced.
/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.debian.org_dists_wheezy_updates_contrib_i18n_Translation-en synced.
/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.debian.org_dists_wheezy_updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages synced.
/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.debian.org_dists_wheezy_updates_main_i18n_Translation-en synced.
/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.debian.org_dists_wheezy_updates_main_source_Sources synced.
/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.debian.org_dists_wheezy_updates_non-free_binary-amd64_Packages synced.
/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.debian.org_dists_wheezy_updates_non-free_i18n_Translation-en synced.
root@CFRLJY1:~# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  krb5-locales libapache2-mod-php5 libfreetype6 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgssapi-krb5-2 libk5crypto3 libkrb5-3
  libkrb5support0 libmysqlclient18 libpng12-0 linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64 mysql-client-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.5
  mysql-server-core-5.5 ntp php-pear php5 php5-cli php5-common php5-curl php5-mysql tzdata
25 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 42.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 217 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
0% [Connecting to cdn.debian.net] [Connecting to security.debian.org]
```

Thanks so much for any hint and help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found out what the problem was and got it to update actual packages. For that to work I had to repeat the whole process twice though.

- create signature file on offline computer
- download package for this signature file on online computer
- install package on offline computer - this time only the apt database was updated, no packages were updated
- create a fresh signature file on offline computer
- download package for this signature file on online computer - this time a lot of packages were downloaded
- import package on online computer - This time apt could finally install the packages, because the packages were synced as well.

The key was doing everything twice, to update the apt database first, then update the packages.

Using apt-offline-debian-1.6.1 from the github repository: https://github.com/rickysarraf/apt-offline/releases

Answer (score 0):

The `apt-offline` output shows that it installed package index files, but no actual packages. I don't know `apt-offline`, but don't you need to tell it to create a bundle for the packages you want to install or upgrade somehow?

Comment: yeah you need to create a bundle on the online computer with the help of the sig file from the offline computer. did all that. then moved the bundle on the offline computer. `apt-offline install /media/usb/bundle-24-11-2015-3.zip` is installing that bundle. Hmm...

Comment: You may have tried that, but the output doesn't show any packages, so something must've gone wrong there..

Comment: I only get to go to the offline computer every two months, but I'll try it again according to the official apt-offline procedure. Even though I have already done that, it seems like I might have done something wrong.